# Label text and Navigation Bar Title changes are not updated in iOS Simulator.

Tags: ios, text, storyboard, label

I have changed the label placeholder text and Navigation Bar Title text in Storyboard, but it is not updated when tested in iOS Simulator.

I have tried to reset the content and settings for iOS Simulator, but it didn't work.

I have set Localization for the Storyboard in other language, but the changes I made is in the base language and the iOS Simulator is in English and text never changed.

Other things I made to Storyboard is update in iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure it out! I had deleted the english language in Localizations setting before. Because I thought the base language will always be English. But it was wrong.

If you delete the english in localizations, then other language will be the base language, even when the iOS setting choose English and USA, and the text you input in storyboardName.storyboard(Base) is english, it will show other language you choose to localization instead.